# Modifying reference style in thesis template

Tags: biblatex, templates, thesis, bibliographystyle

I'm trying to modify the reference style in the [Cambridge engineering thesis template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-for-cambridge-university-engineering-department-cued-latex-xelatex-and-lualatex-support-v2-dot-1/kgfqybfnqkdf) to display references in the bibliography in AIP-like style at the request of my supervisor.
The default bibliography options in the template are:

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nty, natbib=True]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References/references}

\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography
 
...
\end{document}
```

Currently, this produces references with the article title but no journal name (among other differences from AIP style)

I've tried changing `style=numeric-comp` to `style=phys`, but this doesn't affect the bibliography.

I tried changing the above to:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References/references.bib}

\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
...
\end{document}
```

However, on the first compilation run this results in my document compiling without a bibliography, and all of my in-text citations showing up as the citation key (e.g. [ji2009]), rather than numerical references or as **??**, and on the second compilation run it fails to produce a pdf (I am using overleaf, but similarly failed to compile when I tried separate biber and pdflatex compiles using Texmaker). It seemed to fail where bibliography keys were in the format 'name2009a' (for example, being OK with 'li2019' but failing when both 'li2009' and 'li2009a' were included), but this may be a coincidence.

Is there a way to change this to either use the `phys` option, or modify the fields displayed by the bibliography?

The below is also included in the .cls file - I am using `custombib` in the class options:

```
% ******************************* Bibliography *********************************
\newif\ifsetBib\setBibfalse                   % Custom Bibliography = true/false
\newif\ifsetBiBLaTeX\setBiBLaTeXfalse         % BiBLaTeX = True / False

\newif\ifPHD@biblatex\PHD@biblatexfalse       % BiBLaTeX
\DeclareOption{biblatex}{
  \ifsetBib
    \ClassWarning{PhDThesisPSnPDF}{Bibliography selection conflict: A
      bibliography style aleady specified. Please check the document class
      options in case you have defined two bibliography styles.}
  \else
    \PHD@biblatextrue
  \fi
}

\newif\ifPHD@authoryear\PHD@authoryearfalse   % Author-Year citation
\DeclareOption{authoryear}{
  \ifsetBib
    \ClassWarning{PhDThesisPSnPDF}{Bibliography selection conflict: A
      bibliography style aleady specified. Please check the document class
      options in case you have defined two bibliography styles.}
  \else
    \PHD@authoryeartrue
    \setBibtrue
  \fi
}

\newif\ifPHD@numbered\PHD@numberedfalse       % Numbered citiation
\DeclareOption{numbered}{
  \ifsetBib
    \ClassWarning{PhDThesisPSnPDF}{Bibliography selection conflict: A
      bibliography style aleady specified. Please check the document class
      options in case you have defined two bibliography styles.}
  \else
    \PHD@numberedtrue
    \setBibtrue
  \fi
}

\newif\ifuseCustomBib\useCustomBibfalse     % Custom Bibliography
\DeclareOption{custombib}{
  \ifsetBib
    \ClassWarning{PhDThesisPSnPDF}{Bibliography selection conflict: A
      bibliography style aleady specified. Please check the document class
      options in case you have defined two bibliography styles.}
  \else
    \ifPHD@biblatex
        \ClassWarning{PhDThesisPSnPDF}{Bibliography selection conflict: A
          bibliography style aleady specified. Please check the document class
          options in case you have defined two bibliography styles.}
    \else
      \useCustomBibtrue
      \setBibtrue
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Comment: If your objective is to emulate the `unsrt` bibliography style -- or, better yet, the `unsrtnat` style, which is `natbib`'s reimplementation of the old `unsrt` style -- while using `biblatex` and `biber`, you should run `\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=trad-unsrt]{biblatex}` in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your help - my objective is to display the references in the bibliography using the AIP reference style (which I believe corresponds to `phys` in biblatex styles). I need the references to display as e.g. A. Author, Journal Abbrv., Volume(issue), first page, (year). The current display style is Firstname Lastname, Article Title, Volume(Issue):page

Comment: \
I have a similar problem with the difference that I just want bibtex to work. I followed the steps you mentioned but after compiling it appears: ```Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'backref'. \begin{document} ``` What will be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the root cause of the issue with compilation - adding it here in case someone else is searching for something similar in future!

Note that the CUED (Cambridge University Eng Dept) thesis template .cls file has two sections dealing with references and bibliography. If you do need to remove all the template defaults and replace with your own set-up, make sure to remove/ comment out **both** subsections from the .cls file!

To replace the default references with AIP/ `phys` style references:

1. Removed **both** subsections related to references/ bibliography from the .cls file
2. Removed all settings for references from the preamble file and replaced with `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=phys]{biblatex} \addbibresource{References/references.bib}`
3. Retained only the following class settings:
   `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}`

The issue causing other references to fail (especially `@online` references with urls) involved a custom command I'd set up. As I use subscripts outside of equations extremely frequently, early on I set the following shortcut:

`\let\sb\textsubscript`

It turns out there is an `\sb` command which plays a role in printing the bibliography/ url formatting/ *something* in `@online` references.

After a lot of find and replace searches in all my sub-documents to remove `\sb`, everything is finally working smoothly. It's taken several weeks of re-constructing and painstaking searching for issues, and I realise it's very specific to my custom shortcut, but hopefully this can save someone some time!

(For context, the reason for the change from default template settings to `phys` style was my supervisor's specification)